# Avoiding Iteration to get Count of Occurences in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, one of which contains a list of bus stop numbers, `df_stops`, the other contains bus arrivals, `df_arrivals`, (`StopNumber` and `OnTimeStatus` = `-1`, `0`, or `1` which corresponds to if the bus was early, on time, or late, respectively).

I'm looking to add 3 new columns to the `df_stops` DataFrame:

1. `PercentEarly`
2. `PercentOnTime`
3. `PercentLate`

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this without doing it iteratively using loops. If I were to do it iteratively, I would do something along the lines of:

```
for row in df_stops:
    # number of early arrivals / total number of arrivals @ that stop
    row['PercentEarly'] =
        df_arrivals.loc[df_arrivals['StopNum'] == row['StopNum'] and df_arrivals['OnTimeStatus'] < 0].count() 
        / df_arrivals.loc[df_arrivals['StopNum'] == row['StopNum']].count()

    # same idea for on time and late arrivals
```

I'm relatively new to Pandas and data science in general, so any help is appreciated.

**How can I do this without iterating over every row in `df_stops`?**

EDIT:

`df_arrivals`

```
       RouteNumber  ScheduledUnix  StopNumber OnTimeStatus
0               44     1511977533       40888            0
1               44     1511979273       40888            0
2               44     1511979273       40888            0
3               44     1511980353       40888            0
4               44     1511979273       40888            0
5               44     1511980353       40888            1
...            ...            ...         ...          ...
67538           85     1512005100       40900            0
67539           85     1512008700       40900            0
67540           85     1512008700       40900           -1
67541           85     1512008700       40900            0
67542           85     1512012300       40900            0
```

`df_stops`:

```
     StopNumber
0         40877
1         40874
2         40876
3         40725
4         40875
5         40776
6         40730
7         40723
8         40721
9         40729
10        40722
```

Desired output would looks something like:

```
     StopNumber    EarlyPercent    OnTimePercent    LatePercent
0         40877            0.14             0.80           0.06
...
```

Comment: Add examples of your dataframes so people don't have to guess

Comment: I would do a value_counts() on the below suggestion by ErroriSalvo then just take the values and update using conditional logic. I.E. if df.loc[df.StopNum == 2, 'PercentEarly'] = percentEarly

Comment: @codebrotherone added some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up figuring out how to do it without iteration. I also decided to store the number of early/on-time/late instead of the percentage. Here's my solution that seems to be decently fast even given tens of thousands of entries:

```
# find the number of arrivals, make a series, and merge it with the stops DataFrame
df_stop_counts = df_arrivals['stopNumber'].value_counts().reset_index()
df_stop_counts.columns = ['StopNumber', 'NumArrivals']
df_stops = pd.merge(df_stops, df_stop_counts, left_on='stopNumber', right_on='StopNumber')

# iterate over all the stops and find the number of early/on-time/late arrivals
for index, row in df_stops.iterrows():
    df_stops.at[index, 'NumEarly'] = len(df_arrivals.loc[(df_arrivals['stopNumber'] == index) & (df_arrivals['OnTimeStatus'] == -1)])
    df_stops.at[index, 'NumOnTime'] =  len(df_arrivals.loc[(df_arrivals['stopNumber'] == index) & (df_arrivals['OnTimeStatus'] == 0)])
    df_stops.at[index, 'NumLate'] =  len(df_arrivals.loc[(df_arrivals['stopNumber'] == index) & (df_arrivals['OnTimeStatus'] == 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby

```
for stops in df_arrivals.groupby('StopNum'):
    stop[1].groupby('OnTimeStatus').count()
```

Does it work as expected now?

Comment: Chaining `groupby()` gives the following error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: Ok then you might need a for loop

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on count of occurrences:

What I would do is:

```
#This represents all early, ontime, and late arrivals. If you want to grab per stopnum then you need to groupby first (see below)
#Define a specific stop num and store as stop_num = the number
early, ontime, late = df_arrivals[df_arrivals.stop_number == stop_num].OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[-1], df_arrivals.OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[0], df_arrivals.OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[1]

total_stops = len(df_stops[df_stops.StopNumber == stop_num])
EarlyPercent= early/total_stops
OntimePercent= ontime/total_stops
LatePercent= late/total_stops
```

Now keep in mind that this is only per one stop num. I actually don't think there is a way to avoid iterations in this case without overly complex code (chaining, etc...).

```
df_stops['PercentEarly'] = ''
df_stops['PercentOntime'] = ''
df_stops['PercentLate'] = ''

for stop_num in df_arrivals.stop_number.tolist():
    early, ontime, late = df_arrivals[df_arrivals.stop_number == stop_num].OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[-1], df_arrivals.OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[0], df_arrivals.OnTimeStatus.value_counts()[1]
    total_stops = len(df_stops[df_stops.StopNumber == stop_num])
    EarlyPercent= early/total_stops
    OntimePercent= ontime/total_stops
    LatePercent= late/total_stops
    df_stops.loc[df_stops.StopNumber == stop_num, 'PercentEarly'] =EarlyPercent
    df_stops.loc[df_stops.StopNumber == stop_num, 'PercentOnTime'] = OntimePercent
    df_stops.loc[df_stops.StopNumber == stop_num, 'PercentLate'] =LatePercent
```